How do you turn pairs from a dataframe column into two new columns
I've been trying to take a DataFrame like df below, and turning some of the columns (say B_m and B_n) into two columns (call them B_m1, B_m2, B_n1 and B_n2), for each pair of values in that column (akin to itertools.combinations(col, r=2)), where they share the same group number. So for B_m, the rows where Group is 0, we should get that B_m1 = [-1, -1, 0] and B_m2 = [0, 1, 1].
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 7, -1, 0.9],
        [0, 4, 7, 0, 0.3],
        [0, 4, 7, 1, 0.2],
        [1, 3, 3, 1, 0.5],
        [1, 3, 3, 0, 0.2],
        [2, 1, 8, 0, 0.6],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'],
)
print(df)

In the case there is only 1 row with a given group, it should be removed. For 4 or more rows with the same group number, we should similarly find all repetitions without repeats.
Shown below is what the expected result should look like.
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 7, -1, 0, 0.9, 0.3],
        [0, 4, 7, -1, 1, 0.9, 0.2],
        [0, 4, 7, 0, 1, 0.3, 0.2],
        [1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.2],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m1', 'B_m2', 'B_n1', 'B_n2'],
)
print(expected)

My first attempt not only took ages to run, using some awkard looping and making a new DataFrame (not elegant and don't have it saved), but also didn't work. Since then, I've not been able to come up with an alternative solution.
For the record, I did post a similar, but different question about 3 months ago, if that is of any inspiration.

What should happen if the last row is [1, 3, 4, 0, 0.2]? Or if you have 4 rows in a group?

@mozway I realized that I made a mistake in my DF's. The none-B columns are supposed to be the same for each Group. So all A's for group 0 should be identical. Updating that now. Also, I forgot to mention that if there is only 1 row in a "group", it should be removed. Also adding that now.

What about the groups of 4 rows? This creates 6 combinations, how should the output look like? Would you only keep the first 4? Get 6 rows in the output? What is the maximum size of a group?

It should be 6 combinations. There is technically no max size, but the bigger the group size, the more rare they become (I think exponentially decaying).

Got it, see my answer below ;)

Here is an approach with groupby.apply and concat:
from itertools import combinations

cols = ['B_m', 'B_n']
group = list(df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False))

g = df.groupby(group, sort=False)

out = pd.concat((g[c].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(x, r=2))))
                     .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{c}{x+1}')
                for c in cols), axis=1).reset_index(group)

Output:
   Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_m2  B_n1  B_n2
0      1    4    7  -1.0   0.0   0.9   0.3
1      1    4    7  -1.0   1.0   0.9   0.2
2      1    4    7   0.0   1.0   0.3   0.2
0      2    3    3   1.0   0.0   0.5   0.2


Thank you. I'd completely forgotten about groupby. That was the idea that was missing. I do like your way of implementing this too, something to learn from.

Here is a join-based approach, relying on the fact that equality joins produce the cartesian product of results within the equality groups. Once we have that, it's a matter of filtering down to the unique combinations (which is done by filtering on the produced group_count column):
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 7, -1, 0.9],
        [0, 4, 7, 0, 0.3],
        [0, 4, 7, 1, 0.2],
        [1, 3, 3, 1, 0.5],
        [1, 3, 3, 0, 0.2],
        [2, 1, 8, 0, 0.6],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'],
)

combo_cols = ['B_m', 'B_n']

print(
    df.assign(group_count=lambda d: d.groupby('Group').cumcount())
    .pipe(lambda d:
          d.merge(
              d[['Group', 'group_count', *combo_cols]], on='Group', how='left', suffixes=('1', '2')
          )
    )
    .query('group_count1 < group_count2')
    .drop(columns=['group_count1', 'group_count2'])
    [['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m1', 'B_m2', 'B_n1', 'B_n2']]
)

#     Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_m2  B_n1  B_n2
# 1       0    4    7    -1     0   0.9   0.3
# 2       0    4    7    -1     1   0.9   0.2
# 5       0    4    7     0     1   0.3   0.2
# 10      1    3    3     1     0   0.5   0.2


That's an interesting approach, but it will generate more than twice the number of needed values in the intermediate.
